# Embeding iframes in Stack Overflow answers for examples

Tags: discussion, answers, images

I found most code editors have a "Embed on your page option", I think it would be great if you could embed `<iframes>` in answers and questions.

Comment: OK i see now its a bad idea

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think this is a good idea. `<iframe>`'s in most cases load external content and run into the [similar problem link only answers do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). The external content can go dead, and the content is lost forever. Why not just bring that content into the Stack Exchange ecosystem instead of hosting it elsewhere?

Not to mention the issues with loading external resources over SSL. And as iStimple mentions, Stack Exchange can't control what is being loaded via that iframe (think drive by downloads, or alert popups).

Comment: yeah i see what you mean, it would be a bad idea!.

Comment: or mature content that only shows to 1% of  the viewers (so that any potential offensive flags will be invalidated with 99% probability)

Comment: Was just thinking if stackexchange can allow embedding iframes that have stakexchange page as source. So, basically stackexchange need an editor which will filter / preprocess what can be embedded. Something like image uploader which uploads image to imgur. But, instead of directly uploading iframe source page to stackexchange, it will preprocess / filter it before uploading source page. Another simple approach may be selectively allow famous source domains, like desmos for graphs. This will eliminate eliminate hassle of first apporch and can quickly grow list of allowed source domains.